# does pocketsphinx work with ros hydro?

Tags: ros, pocketsphinx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to find a speech processor to convert from audio to text and was wondering if pocketsphynx package which is available here works with ros hydro because the tutorial asks us to use rosmake which was used for ros fuerte.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/121711/does-pocketsphinx-work-with-ros-hydro?/) by [uzair](https://answers.ros.org/users/8341/uzair/) on ROS Answers with karma: 87 on 2014-01-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) on 2014-01-24**:
What tutorial? Could you post a link? The main page on the wiki is updated http://wiki.ros.org/pocketsphinx

**Comment by [uzair](https://answers.ros.org/users/8341/uzair/) on 2014-01-24**:
http://www.pirobot.org/blog/0022/ I was talking about this tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The tutorials you are looking at are probably out of date. The hydro-devel branch on github: https://github.com/mikeferguson/pocketsphinx is updated to use catkin, and is also released to debians (so you can install via "sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-pocketsphinx")

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2014-01-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [uzair](https://answers.ros.org/users/8341/uzair/) on 2014-01-24**:
THank you so much for the help. I'll try it out.

**Comment by [uzair](https://answers.ros.org/users/8341/uzair/) on 2014-01-29**:
I downloaded the new version and it all works fine. Thnaks.

**Comment by [Gulfboy64](https://answers.ros.org/users/21534/gulfboy64/) on 2015-02-01**:
I'm getting ready to try the mikeferguson/pocketsphinx ver. Do you still need sphinxbase in the installation?
Thanks,  Gulfbo64